# PHP Loops within Loops

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I have code as follows:

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($rowprev = mysql_fetch_array($resultprev)){

    // Do stuff

    }
}
```

The questions I have, if the `Row Count` from `$resultprev` = `0` is there anyway to not allow the `if` statement to run?

Example:

```
$num_rows_resultprev = mysql_num_rows($resultprev);    

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($num_rows_resultprev > 0){
        if($rowprev = mysql_fetch_array($resultprev)){
        }
    // Do something

    }
}
```

Comment: Use the && link, which is "AND" logic. `if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $num_rows_resultprev > 0)`

Comment: Have you tried running your 'Example'? Does it not work the way you expect, or do you get any errors?

Comment: You entangled in your loops and trying to entangle others. What prolem you are trying to solve with your loops? It seems it has way more common and plain solution.

Comment: @RyanP - oddly the above code stops the page from running - yet when I change the > 0 to == 0, the code runs.  But it shouldn't as the line 'if($rowprev = mysql_fetch_array($resultprev)){' will stop the page if it's rowcount is 0....

Comment: @Homer_J Well that would make it seem like `$resultprev` didn't have any rows in it... where do you assign `$resultprev`? Is this part of a bigger loop you could post?

Comment: @RyanP - that is correct `$resultprev` doesn't have any rows and therefore, in that situation I don't want the `if($rowprev = mysql_fetch_array($resultprev)){' to run.  It is indeed part of a much much larger loop that builds a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two notes:

1) mysql_num_rows is unreliable, perhaps try a count query:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

> Note:
>
> If you use mysql_unbuffered_query(), mysql_num_rows() will not return
>   the correct value until all the rows in the result set have been
>   retrieved.

2) your mysql_fetch_array may actually be returning something (eval to true).

Check the values of your variables and result sets.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your question but I'm not entirely clear what your question is...

Change

```
if($rowprev = mysql_fetch_array($resultprev)){
```

To

```
if($rowprev = mysql_fetch_array($resultprev) && $rowprev != 0){
```

Is that all you were asking for?